# Image Mapster Fails HTML Validation

Tags: jquery, imagemapster

I'm having problems validating my page which is using imagemapster.

Error Line 326, Column 39: there is no attribute "name"

```
<area name="slice-1" shape="poly" coords="24…
```

But if I remove name the imagemap no longer works!

.

See the vegetable demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/

If I delete redpepper then if doesn't work

```
<area shape="poly" name="redpepper"
```

So how do I get imagemappster to work and validate on my page?

ps my doctype is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" >
```

Comment: Hi! It doesn't give me any errors. It's working pretty fine. Did the error appears in the console while executing the jsfiddle?

Comment: It's the W3C HTML validator that's saying there's an error when validating the page, the name attribute is not allowed on the area tag.  The actual code works fine, it's just not validating.